# Writing dynamic SQL query using execute immediate

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have written a PLSQL code where I am trying to introduce execute immediate statement
but in that need to create SQL statement dynamically

Below is my following statement something is fishy in this not getting executed

```
tblname := 'emp';
v_tbl   := 'emp_123';

execute immediate 'CREATE TABLE' || tblname || '  AS select * from ' || v_tbl;
```

Any solution is much appreciated

Comment: You are missing a space after `'CREATE TABLE`. It should be `'CREATE TABLE '`

Answer (score 2):

You have not declared the datatype of variables and also make sure that emp_123 table is available in the schema. Below is the sample code:

```
DECLARE

  Tblname VARCHAR2(6) := 'emp';
  v_Tbl   VARCHAR2(9) := 'emp_123';
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE ' || Tblname || '  AS select * from ' || v_Tbl;
END;
```

Comment: Did this solution worked for your issue?